# How to handle .yarnc in pnpm? Installing private from registry?

Tags: node.js, pnpm

How to handle .yarnrc in pnpm?

Should I convert it somehow to pnpm equivalent of .yarnrc but I can't find any existing.

So should pnpm use .yarnrc? but it doesn't seem to be able to handle it...

Currently it have problems to fetch libraries for example from artifactory (jfrog) where links to private repositories are provided for yarn in .yarnrc

Can't find it in the doc nor googling...

I'm little bit confused how to approach this

Answer (score 2):

pnpm supports npm configuration files, so you can add this to `.npmrc`:

```
registry=...
```

It should have the same value as `npmRegistryServer` in your `.yarnrc` (which you can delete).